# Play .mp4 videos using Irrlicht

Tags: irrlicht

In the game I'm making, I'll sometimes need to play videos of the .mp4 format. Does Irrlicht support .mp4 playback? And if so, can anyone recommend a good tutorial on doing so?

Comment: [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

Comment: There's someone implement with OpenCV, but with the .avi format, if helps: [demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vvp-08yegI) [code](http://nashruddin.com/how_to_play_avi_files_with_opencv)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Slightly longer answer: you can use irrlicht to display video (for instance by updating a texture you're displaying), but you have to handle the decoding in some other way. Based on a quick googling, [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) seems a popular answer.

[Here](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=46401) is a thread at irrlicht forums asking exactly the same thing you asked here.

Personally, I'd suggest using some other format than mp4 due to licensing issues, such as [xiph theora](http://www.theora.org/) (cool guys, horrible project names).